# Settlement price of SPX

Tags: spx, settlement

How would the settlement price of SPX be determined if market is closed on the expiration date due to natural disasters/terrorist attacks?

Comment: Most probably would be the last traded price before the closure...

Comment: Your question is about SPX settle for options pricing?

Comment: it's about the settlement price for futures/options

Comment: And this is not covered in the settlement procedures? I don't know, just curious. https://www.cmegroup.com/confluence/display/EPICSANDBOX/Standard+and+Poors+500+Futures

Comment: It seems not...

Comment: There are rules in place of course, but in a an unforeseen situation the exchange has some discretion as to what they will do, a person or commitee will have to make a decision then and there.